# Error about graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I used this link: http://graph.facebook.com/807470072639300/photos/?limit=1&offset=3, It works OK But when I used http://graph.facebook.com/807470072639300/photos/, It doesn't work. Please help me to find out the reason. Many thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug to me. You can report this at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/